# How to handle misattribution / putting words into people's mouths in answers

Tags: discussion, attribution

Imagine if someone asked a question about Python, and an answer were to say:

> "Guido van Rossum would say that this is a case of PPM..."

...and then proceeded to fill their entire post referring to "PPM", which stands for "Python Procedural Machine", an acronym that no one on the Internet uses except this person on their own personal Python site--and which Guido van Rossum has most certainly never used.

Someone did basically this (except for Rebol).  [So I changed it to "I would say"](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40099234/3), which they rolled back.

Their answer is pretty bad regardless of the self-styled acronym spam.  But there's something about putting your bad answer's words in the mouth of the creator of the language that seems like it should be fixed instead of just downvoted.

UPDATE: I may not have to fight much of a moderation battle with this person, as they are [helping me out a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40099234/5) with my case.

Comment: How would you expect a moderator to be qualified to judge whether or not a given sentiment is in line with a person's views? (The post isn't asserting that the individual stated anything in particular, so merely providing evidence that they never stated a quoted section wouldn't be applicable here.)

Comment: @Servy Wikipedia would bias it as "citation required", e.g. if there's contention over such a point you have to provide a link as evidence.  *If you're going to answer for someone other than yourself*, that seems a reasonable thing (at least if anyone considers it worth disputing).

Comment: Sure.  It's *entirely* appropriate to expect someone to support a claim that they've made.  If they've made a claim that you feel is false, or even just inadequately supported with facts/references/etc., by all means, downvote.  But a moderator can't be expected to judge such technical merits of a post.  Mods don't go around deleting posts because their claims aren't sufficiently substantiated (or even if they're provably wrong) that's what voting's for.

Comment: @Servy so I can attribute any opinion that I want to you in an answer (when you're on vacation, and not here to react yourself) and that's ok?  This is specifically a question about *attributing views and statements to other people in your answer* ...not about the technical accuracy of statements given in a vacuum.  I think there's a higher bar for evidence in that case, especially when the answer is bad/wrong.

Comment: But he *didn't* claim that the user did/said anything in particular.  It's one thing to say, "HostileFork said that he's a pink fluffy bunny" and something rather different to say, "HostileFork seems like he's probably a pink fluffy bunny".  This user isn't claiming that a particular person said a specific thing, he's expressing *his own opinion* about the opinion/views of another person.

Comment: @Servy So you're saying that "would say" is sufficiently subjunctive to dodge an attribution requirement, while "says" or "said" would perhaps be held to a different standard?   (And [RE:bunnies...the police cleared that one up for me, already.  :-/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxYtSOv_In4)

Comment: You're once again assuming a moderator enforced base attribution requirement.  Mods don't go around deleting posts because they make claims without providing attribution for them.

Comment: @Servy It's not about going around deleting posts.  Just that if there's potential for a rollback war over a point of attribution to someone besides the answerer of the post, that the resolution of said dispute would lean to "citation required".  And this would be special due to the circumstance of putting words in someone else's mouth--not the duty of having to day-to-day fact check technical points.

Comment: So then you're saying "deleting portions of posts" rather than "deleting entire posts"  the point remains the same.  Moderators don't go around editing out portions of posts because the author hasn't provided a citation for an assertion that they made.

Comment: @Servy Again, this isn't about hunting down cases and doing it un-asked.  It's about resolving disputes.  So the idea being if there's an edit, then a rollback, a person can either walk away and say *"original poster wins, whatever they said stands"* or try and bring it to moderation and reference a policy for why the edit should stand.  e.g. people adding back in signatures or other stuff, there's a post somewhere that says "don't put signatures" and that wins.  So I am trying to set precedent for such resolutions when they occur.

Comment: But you're asking the moderators to make a judgement of the technical merits of of a post, and to say that your edit should win because you're right.  And on top of that, it's a matter of opinion (in this case) to begin with, so you're asking a moderator to say that your opinion is right and his is not, so your edit should stand.  Saying "mods should only ever do it when someone asks them to" doesn't change that.  A mod doesn't need to understand anything about the content to know that something is a signature and should be removed; it's something they can always judge for *any* post.

Comment: I asked Knuth for an opinion about this question and he said "That question genuinely made me dumber. What's an algorithm?"

Comment: @Servy I disagree--it's clear to see when someone is writing something from their own voice, vs. saying someone else said it.  Such a distinction is as easy as telling if there is a signature or isn't one.  Then, just add the idea that if someone has a problem with the lack of citation of that person saying that thing...(enough to bring it to moderator attention)...that unless it is supported with a citation...it is either removed, or the statement just given from the original author's voice minus any attribution.  It can be divorced from any question of "technical merit".

Comment: @HostileFork This post is not writing something that it claims someone else said, so then by your own logic, your proposed rule doesn't apply to it.

Comment: @Servy You've said that "X would say" and "X said" are different, and while I can accept that, it doesn't mean an answer to this meta-question couldn't establish a precedent if something did say "X said" in the future.  *(As for the provoking post here, it's gone, after the OP...who is a well-established nuisance in non-SO forums...didn't understand other people were editing him, and [went off in his typical style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095593/whats-the-difference-between-a-b-1-and-a-b-1-in-red/40099234#comment67502688_40099234)...hopefully not to return.)*

Comment: If you would like to discuss the situation where someone provided a *direct quote* that isn't attributed, and that is entirely unrelated to the example you're currently discussing, then by all means, edit your question accordingly.  If you do, the comments here could largely be deleted.

Comment: @Servy I'm with Hostile on this: writing "Person X would say" implies that they know what that person is thinking, and they seem to be using it to try to lend weight to their answer rather than just making a good answer.  Unless the person actually said it or you are the person, there's no way to know what they would say, and no reason to word it that way.

Comment: Mostly it just seems like fluff though, I'd remove the phrase "person x would say" just like I'd remove "I would say", and instead just say the thing.

Comment: @davidism And what if that person does in fact know what they would say?  In this one example the person (apparently) is very wrong about it, but there are plenty of people who've made a particular sentiment clear, and someone may choose to bring that up without feeling the need to provide an exact quote.  For example, I might say that Jeff Atwood would say that we should strive to improve the quality of questions asked on this site, and not see a need to provide an exact quote.  Should such a sentiment be prohibited?

Comment: @Servy yeah, I'd probably be wary of that statement too.  Just because his stance is known, doesn't mean that's how he would say it.  You're assigning someone else's authority to your interpretation.

Comment: @davidism You're entirely within your rights to not find such an argument compelling, to not lend weight to such a statement, or to contest its validity, but to universally prohibit all such statements, without question, is quite another matter.

Comment: @Servy I don't think we should prohibit them. I think we should definitely question their validity, which the op did in this case.  I don't think op is asking to prohibit them either, but instead looking for a way to address or improve them.  Which I agree with, there are probably better ways to invoke external authority. (And yes, I interpreted op's intentions here. :-/ )

Comment: @davidism The OP is asserting that he should be able to edit out such content, and have a mod enforce his edit in the event the author rolls it back.  That's prohibiting that content.  Like I said, you're *entirely* within your rights to not lend weight to such content, or to reflect your opinion of its usefulness in votes, but to never allow anyone to ever write a post that contains it is *quite* different.

Comment: This comment from under the answer is an absolute classic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlF0i.png Trollololololol.